# auto-return `source`d script on command failure

Tags: bash

How do I make a `source`d script auto-return if any command inside it fails?

Suppose I have a script that auto-exits on failure via `set -e`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# foo.env
set -e        # auto-exit on any command failure
echo "hi"
grep 123 456  # this command will fail (I don't have a file named "456")
echo "should not reach here"
```

If I run the command normally, it will auto-exit on the failed `grep` command:

```
box1% ./foo.env
hi
grep: 456: No such file or directory
```

However, if I `source` the script, it exits my current shell, not just the script being sourced:

```
box1% ssh box2
box2% source ./foo.env
hi
grep: 456: No such file or directory
Connection to box2 closed.
box1%
```

If I remove the `set -e`,

```
#!/bin/bash
# foo2.env
echo "hi"
grep 123 456  # this command will fail (I don't have a file named "456")
echo "should not reach here"
```

then it doesn't auto-exit or auto-return the `source`d script at all:

```
box1% ssh box2
box2% source ./foo2.env
hi
grep: 456: No such file or directory
should not reach here
box2%
```

The only workaround I've found so far is to add a `return` expression to every line of code in the script, e.g.

```
box1% cat foo3.env
#!/bin/bash
# foo3.env - works, but is cumbersome
echo "hi" || return
grep 123 456 || return
echo "should not reach here" || return

box1% source foo3.env
hi
grep: 456: No such file or directory
box1%
```

Is there another way for `source`d scripts, similar to how `set -e` works for non-`source`d ones?

Answer (score 1):

When you `source` a script is like if you were writing that file  line by line from the keyboard. It means that `set -e` will regard the current shell and that on error it will exit from the current shell.

That's a workaround. Today I feel me lazy so I thought that computer can write `||return` for me, or better to read line by line the file and execute so:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is the file MySource.sh
while IFS='' read -r line
do
   [[ $line == \#* ]] || $line || return
done < "$1"
```

execute it with `. MySource.sh FileToBeSourced.sh`

**If your *FileToBeSourced.sh* script is with one line commands it should work.**
Far far away to be ready to be used in a production environment.
Test it and eventually **use it at your own risk**.

It skips lines that start with `#` because they should cause the error `# command not found`.

Comment: That's a clever trick.  It turns out my scripts span many lines, so I'd have to make a fancier parser.  Maybe the best way is to find a parser or hack one up in Perl and have it stream commands instead of `read`.

Comment: @MrFooz: Thanks, it was just an idea. With a _fancy parser_ you can get rid of the ungraceful `[[ $line == \#* ]]  || ` too. Maybe you can put the _parsed output_ at the end of the loop `do.. done <<< $( FancyParser.sh "$1" )`